# Is a continuous function $f$ from a metric space $(X, d)$ to $\mathbb{R}$ compact under some certain condition?

Tags: real-analysis

$(X, d)$ is a metric space with metric $d$ and there is $x_0 \in X$ and define $E_\epsilon=\{x\in X, d(x, x_0)\geq \epsilon\}$. If $f$ is continuous function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(E_\epsilon)$ is compact for $\forall \epsilon>0$. Prove that $f(X)$ is compact.

I only know that $f(X)=\cup_{n=1}^\infty f(E_{\frac{1}{n}})$ and each $f(E_{\frac{1}{n}})$ is compact and $f(E_{\frac{1}{n+1}})\subseteq f(E_{\frac{1}{n}})$then how to prove the union is compact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\{O_i\}$ be an open cover of $f(X)$, we see that $f(x_0)$ must be inside of an open interval $(f(x_0) -\delta, f(x_0)+\delta) \subset O_i^*$ for some $\delta > 0$. By continuity, there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that whenever 
$$d(x,x_0) < \epsilon$$
we have
$$ |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \delta.$$
Thus $f(E_\epsilon^c) \subset O_i^*$ , and $\{O_i\}$ forms an open cover for $f(E_\epsilon)$, there exists a finite subcover $\{O_{i_j}\}$ since $f(E_\epsilon)$ is compact. Now $\{O_{i_j}\} \cup \{O_i^*\}$ forms a finite subcover for $f(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

I give hints only.

1) As $K=f(X)\subset \mathbb{R}$, you have to show a) $K$ is bounded and b) $K$ is closed.

2) For a), use the continuity of $f$ at $x_0$ and your hypothesis.

3) For b), take $b_n\in K$ such that $b_n\to b\in \mathbb{R}$, you have to show that $b\in K$. There exists $a_n \in X$ such that $b_n=f(a_n)$.

4) Case 1: There exists  $\varepsilon_0>0$ and  $N$ such that $n\geq N$ imply $d(a_n,x_0)\geq \varepsilon_0$.

5) Case 2: If we are not in case 1, then show that there exists $n_k$ such that $n_{k+1}>n_k$ and $\displaystyle d(a_{n_k},x_0)<\frac{1}{k}$.